# How can I make product photos with solid-colored backgrounds?

Tags: post-processing, lighting, product-photography, background

I'm trying to achieve an effect so the part of the product photo is filled with a solid color background, something similar to:

[image: www.finerylondon.com]

Currently I have two ideas on how to implement this:

- Shoot a product on white background, cut it, and add background via Photoshop.
- Or find a colored sheet and take a picture in front of it.

What method would you use to achieve effect like on above photo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a rule of thumb if you can do it in-camera then you should.  If nothing else, getting that kind of mask right in post processing can be time consuming and fiddly.  It all adds time to your workflow that you don't really need to spend.

Do it with a backdrop and a coloured sheet - it'll be slightly more difficult to set up initially but once it's done once then it's done for all the products.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought too. I also see some problems with colored glow (reflex) that drops from background to product, which is hard to achieve in post processing. I guess above photo is created with a real blue sheet and lightning, do you agree?

Comment: Talking about that image specifically based on a very quick look: the edge of the blue is not exactly straight which suggests a real background was used.  But the background colour is too perfectly uniform to have been done in-camera which points to some post-processing.  Most likely the item was originally shot against 'a' background sheet/card which could have been any colour but that background colour has been changed afterwards with a flood-fill or something similar.  But anything else would really be a discussion topic, and comments are not intended for discussions.

Comment: If you gel a flash pointed at the background you can have any color with a single white backdrop.